# Entity Framework 6 Entity Modelling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table that I shall call `Batch` and it has a scheme that resembles something like this:

```
BatchId | Created Date | CreatedBy | EngineTypeId
----------------------------------------------------
1       | 2018-05-11   | dbo       |  1
```

The column, `EngineTypeId` is tied to another table that is called `BatchEngineSubType` and has a schema like so:

```
BatchEngineSubTypeId | EngineSubType | Description
---------------------|---------------|------------
1                    | TestEngine    | Dummy text
```

Normally I am able to access the data in my table, via a web page using standard MVC. However, my issue with the above is I need my final output on screen to look like this:

```
 BatchId | Created Date | CreatedBy | EngineSubType
 ----------------------------------------------------
 1       | 2018-05-11   | dbo       |  TestEngine
```

At first, I created a view that pulled from my `Batch` table and joined on the `BatchEngineSubType` table to get my desired outlook. But in doing it this way, I have no way of allowing users to actually modify the data and update the corresponding tables.

I did some googling and found a tutorial on the [fluent api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-the-instructor-entity) so I can do what I need to do all in C# instead of SQL.

Following the tutorial I created a new model I called `BatchEngine` that has the following:

```
public class BatchEngine : IObjectWithState
{
    [Key]
    public int BatchEngineSubTypeId { get; set; }

    public string EngineType { get; set; }
    public string Desciption { get; set; }

    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Batch` model I made some changes to use the new model so that the `fluent API` will pick it up:

```
public class Batch_Adjustment : IObjectWithState
{
    [Key]
    public int BatchId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int BatchEngineTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BatchEngine")]
    public string Engine { get; set; }

    public virtual BatchEngine BatchEngine { get; set; }
}
```

The last step, in my `OnModelCreating` method I am trying to tie the two together like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types<IObjectWithState>().Configure(c => c.Ignore(p => p.State));
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo"); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<BatchEngine>()
        .HasMany(b => b.Desciption).WithMany(i => i.)
        .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey()
             .MapRightKey()
             .ToTable("vwBatchRetention"));


    modelBuilder.Entity<Batch>().ToTable("Batch").HasKey(e => e.BatchId);

}
```

It's in the last step that I'm having problems finishing. Have I set this up correctly? As you'll see in the part that has .`WithMany` the part inside the brackets is unfinished. That is because when I enter the `.` nothing appears.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I think "HasMany" is used to define relationships between entities, so you can use it with navigation properties. But "Desciption" is not a navigation property. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is unclear why you are defining relationship with description field? If you want to display `EngineType` than you can access through `objBatch.BatchEngine.EngineType`

Comment: If you setup Batch and BatchEngineSubType relationship properly you can just use `Include` method to achieve your final output without any other classes like so:

`Batches.SIngleOrDefault(b => b.id == id).Include("BatchEngineSubType").ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

When working with Code First, if you do not follow the conventions when defining your classes, or if you want to change the way the conventions work, you can use the fluent API or data annotations to configure your classes so Code First can map the relationships between your tables.

'HasMany' is one of the fluent API method to define relationship between entities. Only the navigation properties can be used with it to define kind of relationship between those entities i.e. one-to-one, one-to-many etc. In tutorial you are following it is showing relationship between Course and Instructor.

Here you are trying to use "Description" a string property with "HasMany" method, which expects a navigation property. You can find more inforamtion at [Entity Framework Fluent API - Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx).